# Callbacks cases in java

Tags: java, callback

What are the callbacks and which cases do exist? 
There are different cases of callbacks but i cant find them anywhere.
Whats the event of each callback? Anyone who can provide some examples pointing out the part of code that gives birth to the event(if it exists) and the code part that handles the event.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've no idea what you want :)

Comment: You need to explain a bit mroe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well i edit the question to be more specific. I hope it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about Event Listeners.  Check out the Java Tutorials pages: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html Thats what i was asking for but people just negative vote.  :o